# Rad Rich Text Box error on file saving

Tags: asp.net, wpf, telerik, richtextbox

I'm using `RadRichTextBox` for WPF. I have just dragged this control in my MainWindow and when I'm trying to save the document (as Word Document or any format), I get this error:

`Unsupported File Format`

What can I do for this problem?

Comment: Please ask Telerik support.

Comment: what a  supporting comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add these files to my project references:

```
Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.OpenXml for docx;

Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Html for HTML;

Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Xaml for XAML;

Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Rtf for RTF;

Telerik.Windows.Documents.FormatProviders.Pdf for PDF.
```